# Show a collection in laravel from controller on different columns in view

Tags: laravel, loops, foreach, query-builder

got this problem:

I want to show the info from a collection where a publication has a "featured" column in true.

```
$pub_destacadas = Publicaciones::take(3)->where('destacado', '=', 1)->get();
```

The problem is that my layout has 3 elements to fill with this information that have different sizes so i wasn't able to solve this using the chunk() method in the foreach in my blade template, so I tried the following:

```
$individual_destacada = $pub_destacadas->take(1);

$grupo_destacada = $pub_destacadas->take(2);
```

and show them in the view as follows:

```
<div class="publicaciones-destacadas">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Publicaciones Destacadas</h2>


            <div class="row">
                @foreach($individual_destacada as $destacada)
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="item-destacado size-2">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('img/publicaciones/' . $destacada->imagen ) }}">
                        {{ $destacada->titulo }}
                        {{ $destacada->descripcion }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                @endforeach

                <div class="col-md-6">

                    @foreach($grupo_destacada as $destacada)
                    <div class="row doble-publicacion">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="item-destacado size-1">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('img/publicaciones/' . $destacada->imagen ) }}">
                                {{ $destacada->titulo }}
                                {{ $destacada->descripcion }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So... now it shows it correctly in the layout but the first item that the query gets is shown 2 times in this layout. How can I exclude this first element in the second variable where I get the featured publications?

Hope I explained the problem correctly.

Here's the layout:
[image: This is the layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [splice](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-splice).

```
$individual_destacada = $pub_destacadas->splice(1);

$grupo_destacada = $pub_destacadas->splice(2);
```

Comment: Wow, easy to ignore this simple element in the documentation. Works flawlessly. Just had to make some changes to your code:

`$individual_destacada = $pub_destacadas->take(1);

  $grupo_destacada = $pub_destacadas->splice(1);`

That worked exactly how I needed. Thx